# Middleware in angular 7?

Tags: angular, routes, multilingual

Is there like laravel middleware in angular 7 or how to set language of the site through route? (https://example.com/en/about, https://example.com/de/about)

P.S. Currently I'm using [this method](https://medium.com/@DenysVuika/simple-i18n-support-for-your-angular-apps-6138a47eb2a9) for multilingual.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could `subscribe` to the router events, and on `NavigationStart` change the used language in your mentioned translationService approach, though I strongly recommend you to use [ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core)

```
this.router.events.subscribe((event: any): void => {
  if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
     /* You should parse for the language code in the route
       here and use it in the following line. Also make sure that the parsed
       language code is an actual language code */
     this.translationService.use(languageCode).then(() => // do your stuff);
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks for answer. Should I write this code for every components?

Comment: No, you place this in your `app.component.ts`. On every route change this code will be executed.

Comment: please how i can put subscriber on this event